# Google.Script.run not working from sidebar

Tags: google-apps-script, sidebar

I'm working on a script and I can't trigger a google script function from a sidebar. I've seen similar problems but I didn't find a way to solve this one.

Here is my gs file :

```
function selectRiders() {
  
  var selectionSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sélections CD43');
  var selectionLastRow = selectionSheet.getLastRow();
  
  var races = [];
  var cadets = [];
  var juniors = [];
  var ecoles = [];
  
  ...
  
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Call-up');
  html.races = races;
  html.ecoles = ecoles;
  html.cadets = cadets;
  html.juniors = juniors;
  
  html = html.evaluate()
             .setTitle('Convocation équipe départementale');
   
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function test() {
  Logger.log('I was called!');
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

Here is my button inside the Call-up.html file :

```
<button id="send-convocation" class="button3">Envoyer la convocation</button>
    
  <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
```

Here is my script (JavaScript.html):

```
<script>

document.getElementById("send-convocation").addEventListener("click", sendNotification);

function sendNotification() {
  google.script.run.test();
}

</script>
```

My button works fine (I've already checked that of course), but I cannot find a way to trigger my test() function.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Not sure if you can see the `log` from the server side function. But you can test if your function works by doing this: `function test() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue('I was called!')
}` . If the value is added in cell `A1` of the active sheet, it means that your code works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it woks fine actually and you're right ! 
I was looking in the wrong log tool ("I was called" is visible by clicking stackdriver logging).

Comment: Glad you solved your issue :)